# I'm failing to connect to the network when I run Flutter doctor. it's saying A network error occurred while

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform

Can you help me, i'm a beginner in flutter development and I'm facing a challenge. I will attach the screenshot. I have tried to find a solution but I can't. What i found to be the cause of this problem is that' I'm using flutter in China so I can't connect to "https://storage.googleapis.com/"
"https://maven.google.com/".

[!] Network resources
✗ A cryptographic error occurred while checking "https://pub.dev/":
Connection terminated during handshake
You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, your network may be
compromised, or you may have malware installed on your computer.
✗ A network error occurred while checking
"https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/": Operation timed out
✗ A network error occurred while checking "https://github.com/": Operation
timed out

I tried to use VPN because for me to access google in China i need it, but it looks like vpn does't work in Terminal.
I also tried coping vpn config to the Terminal before running flutter doctor and it worked then when i tried to link my app with firebase is stopped working again.
I also tried Changing https://maven.google.com/ to https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/ .

Answer (score 1):

In china, there is restriction on accessing resources hosted on Google servers. This can indeed be a challenge, as many essential Flutter packages and tools are hosted on Google domains. Here are some steps you can try to address the issue -

1. Use VPN
2. Use Mirror repo of flutter and dart -In China, there are community-maintained mirrors of popular repositories like Dart, Flutter, and other packages.

https://docs.flutter.dev/community/china

flutter china - https://flutter.cn/docs/get-started/install

Comment: I tried to use VPN and I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: How can i Use Mirror repo?

Comment: check link in asnwer i have added new link

Comment: https://storage.flutter-io.cn/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/windows/flutter_windows_3.3.0-stable.zip

Comment: Is't this for windows? I'm using MacOs

Comment: https://flutter.cn/docs/get-started/install - download it from here